# Minimising quadratic objective subject to logarithmic inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, logarithms, convex-optimization, quadratics

I need to minimise the following function:
$$ (2a_1 + 2a_2 - 1)^2 + (2a_1 + 2a_3 - 1)^2 $$
subject to:
$$ \sum a_i \log_2 a_i \geq -1 $$
where all the $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$
and $a_i \in [0,1]$ and $\sum a_i = 1 $

What would be the best way to do this analytically?

Comment: Since $\log{a_i}\le 0$ why do you need to assume $\sum{a_i\log{a_i}}\le 1$? Isn’t 0 a better bound?

Comment: @HAMIDINESOUMARE, that was a typo, edited

Comment: Edited again, it is log to the base 2

Answer (score 0):

Let us choose $a_1 = a_4 = 1/2$ and  $ a_2 = a_3 = 0$

This minimizes $ 0 \leq (2a_1 + 2a_2 - 1)^2 + (2a_1 + 2a_3 - 1)^2  = 0$ and satisfies the constraints:

- $\sum a_i =  1 $
- $ \sum a_i \log_2 a_i = \log_2 (1/2) =  -1$, where we have exploited that $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x \log_2 x = 0$.

Comment: I'm so sorry, it is log to the base 2. I've edited the question.

Comment: See the new solution